# Convertir string a número en mascara de oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Estoy intentando ejecutar:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('9.9' ,  '999G999G999G999G999G999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'' ') FROM dual;
```

*Y me sale este resultado ERRONEO*: **`99`**

DEBERÍA SER : `9.9` o ERROR.

¿ Cómo puedo solucionar? ¿ Es la máscara ?

**Edición**

Lo que quiero es que el resultado no sea `99` con `9.9`. Cuando ejecuto `9,9` sale `9,9`. Sin embargo, con `9.9` sale `99` y la coma (`,`) sería para decimales y el punto (`.`) para los miles, y el string de entrada pueden introducir lo que deseen. Espero un error con `9.9` nunca un `99`.

Comment: Interesante. En efecto, Oracle no parece molestarle si tienes *group separators* de más, sin importar cómo definas la máscara. No estoy seguro de la mejor forma de resolver esto.

Comment: Para los interesados, veo que abristes la pregunta en [inglés también](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441934/oracle-convert-a-string-to-number-with-a-mask/42442181#42442181), lo que además llevó a que alguien hiciera la pregunta (mas claramente) aquí también: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4020799. Por lo visto, no hay una solución sencilla. Creo que lo que propone Goerman es lo mas cerca a una solución que se va a encontrar.

Answer (score 1):

¿Que tal si utilizas una expresión regular para validar que el valor ingresado cumpla con tu formato? si NO cumple que te muestre "ERROR" en caso contrario que continue con tu expresión, la cual está bien construida.

Sería algo parecido a:

```
SELECT DECODE (
          (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (
                     '9.9',
                     '(^(\d){1,3}(\.(\d){3}){0,6}(,(\d){0,2}){0,1}$)')
             FROM DUAL),
          '', 'ERROR',
          (SELECT TO_NUMBER ('9.9',
                             '999G999G999G999G999G999G999D99',
                             'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'' ')
             FROM DUAL))
          "RTA"
  FROM DUAL
```

**Explicación de la expresión regular:**

```
(^(\d){1,3}(\.(\d){3}){0,6}(,(\d){0,2}){0,1}$)
```

- `^(\d){1,3}` = La cadena debe iniciar `^` con cualquier dígito `(\d)` el cual se repite Minimo 1, Máximo 3 `{1,3}`
- `(\.(\d){3}){0,6}` = si se tiene un separador de miles `\.` se debe tener tres dígitos obligatoriamiente `(\d){3}`, esto se puede repetir máximo 6 veces o ninguna `{0,6}`
- `(,(\d){0,2}){0,1}$` = finalmente al terminar la cadena `$` puede o no tener una coma con minimo 0 y máximo 2 dígitos `(,(\d){0,2}){0,1}`

> Nota: habría que hacerle pruebas a la expresión regular, para verificar que se comporta como quieres.

Comment: No   funciona, dado que yo pretendo que funcione con 9,9 no con 9.9, y con 9,9 da error. Mi intención es que con la consulta indicada cuando el campo de entrada sea 9.9, 99.9 sea error y no concatene, por lo demás está todo bien.

Comment: Modifique la expresión regular (^(\d){1,3}\.((\d){3}\.){0,6}(\d){3},(\d){1,2}$)
por
(^(\d){1,3}(\.(\d){3}){0,6},(\d){1,2}$)

Comment: Tampoco me vale, dado que estamos eliminando la posibilidad de los números miles como por ejemplo 9.999.999 (ese número es correcto) también correcto (9.999)  y correcto 9.999,22. Lo que no sería correcto es: 9.9 saca 99 y 9.99 saca 999 eso es error. Los demás números son validos dado que la máscara indicada es de puntos y punto y coma decimales

Comment: Hola @BGF Modifique nuevamente la expresión regular y agrege una breve explicación.

Comment: La expresión regular

Comment: la expresion regular : SELECT TO_NUMBER('9.9' ,  '999G999G999G999G999G999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'' ') FROM dual; pretende que cualquier numero en formato string sea convertido a numérico con la máscara indicada. Los miles se separan por punto y los decimales comas. pretendo que salga error con 9.9 dado que no es un número lógico . me entiendes? y cuando ejecuto 9.9 sale 99 y no quiero eso

Comment: Si te entiendo, la alternativa que te doy es una forma diferente de abordar tu problema ya que de entrada TO_NUMBER no logra resolver lo que quieres.

Comment: Buenas noches @Goerman muchas gracias pero dicha alternativa no es lo que necesito. Un saludo